# How to insert a row with a foreign key that references a composite key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, sql-insert, composite-primary-key

I have a mysql table with a composite primary key, and a child table that references the first with a foreign key.

What is the correct syntax for inserting a row of the child table?

How are both parts of the composite key given in the insert statement?

I have these tables;

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parent (
    p_id    INT NOT NULL,
    p_org   INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(p_id, p_org),
    p_name  VARCHAR(12))
ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS child (
    c_id    INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    c_org   INT NOT NULL,
    c_p_id  INT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(c_p_id, c_org) REFERENCES parent(p_id, p_org),
    c_info  VARCHAR(12))
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

After inserting two rows into parent;

```
insert into parent values(100, 1, 'name-1'), (100, 2, 'name-2');
```

I want to insert a row into child.

```
insert into child values(1000, 2, 100, 'info-for-2');
```

but I don't know how to specify the composite key. Instead of **100**, I would like to specify (100 and 2) so that my child row only references the parent with (100 2).

With the insert statement above, my query returns two rows instead of one;

```
select * from parent join child on c_p_id = p_id;
```

returns;

```
p_id    p_org   p_name  c_id    c_org   c_p_id  c_info
100     1       name-1  1000    2       100     info-for-2
100     2       name-2  1000    2       100     info-for-2
```

but would like to get just the row with (100 2).

Would I actually have to specify the c_org on the join?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must specify the c_org on the join:

```
 select * from parent join child on c_p_id = p_id && c_org = p_org;
```

Your foreign key is "c_p_id" and "c_org", not just "c_p_id". You must make the join on all foreign key columns.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You need to specify c_org in join and your query becomes like this:

```
select * from parent join child on c_p_id = p_id and c_org = p_org;
```

This can be seen in the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64e22e/4)

You need to do this because you have a composite foreign Key.

Answer (score 0):

You should start to make a habit of explicitly mentioning the target columns in `INSERT` statements.

Then, if you insert a row into `parent` with

```
INSERT INTO parent
            (p_id,
             p_org)
            VALUES (2,
                    100,
                    'name-2');
```

you insert a row into `child` that references the row in `parent` by using the exact values of `parent`'s primary key tuple into the columns of the `childs` foreign key tuple like

```
INSERT INTO child
            (c_id,
             c_org,
             c_p_id,
             c_info)
            VALUES (1000,
                    2,
                    100,
                    'info-for-2');
```

To join the rows you need to check that all values from the primary key match the foreign key's values in the `ON` clause. Here you can use `AND`.

```
SELECT *
       FROM parent p
            INNER JOIN child c
                       ON c.c_p_id = p.p_id
                          AND c.c_org = p.p_org;
```